# Help understanding “l’inversion absolue”

Tags: grammaire, usage, verbes, niveau-de-langue

I read this sentence in an article by Le Monde:

> Figurent également des dates, dont 1786 et 1787, correspondant à peu près aux années de construction des différentes batteries qui protégeaient la rade de Brest.

I found out this is called l’inversion absolue but I’m having trouble understanding why or when it’s used and I can’t really find any resources on it. Could someone explain it a little bit? It seems to be very formal or literary language. Merci beaucoup !

The article is [here](https://www.lemonde.fr/culture/article/2020/02/25/dans-le-finistere-une-mysterieuse-inscription-sur-un-rocher-enfin-devoilee_6030724_3246.html).

Comment: [This](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01382580/document) is what I think is a good paper on the so-called “absolute inversion”. I expect it will answer your question in depth.

Answer (score 3):

In *[Using French](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=wORPDSkLZKYC&pg=PA220)*, inversion is explored under section 3.3.4:

> Inversion, it should be noted, is frequently a marked of formal, refined language.

... after which it then proceeds to list a few examples of usage.

It is the first one that applies here:

> Often in the official variety of French, when a long subject ... would delay the appearance of the verb and thus impair comprehension.

At root, the quoted sentence, in canonical SV (subject-verb) order, is:

> *Des dates [...] figurent également.*

But because the interesting section is that portion marked by `[...]`, it needs to be *focalised*. Instead of leaving it in the middle, the interesting section is postponed to the end, and the subject of the sentence has to be carried along with it: [postposition of the subject](https://www.modernlanguagesopen.org/articles/10.3828/mlo.v0i0.189/).

What makes this example *inversion absolue* (as opposed to another type of *inversion*) is the fact that there is no preceding relative clause marker such as *ce que*, nor a location/time expression such as *l’endroit où* or *au fil des jours*. The sentence goes straight into the verb, and thus it is motivated solely by the consideration above.